# How can I create an svg tag with the same dimention as the browser window?

Tags: html, svg, browser

Suppose, I have the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Protein Structure Analyzer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-strip">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('jobs_table') }}">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="angry-grid">
    <form>
        <div class="header-div">SURPASS Plots</div>
        <div class="form-div">
            <div id="viewer_box" class="box"></div>
            <button id="show_hide" >Show/hide</button>
            <button id="rem" >Remove</button>
            <button id="color" >Color</button>
            <button id="zoom" >Zoom</button>
        </div>
        <div class="plot-div">
            <svg  id="svg" 
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  class="right" width="window.innerWidth" height="window.innerHeight">
            </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-div">
            Footer
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is an SVG tag in the page.

I want this tag to automatically acquire the dimension of the browser window.

Therefore, I wrote

```
<svg ... width="window.innerWidth" height="window.innerHeight" ...></svg>
```

However, this is raising error in the browser's debug console:

```
Error: <svg> attribute width: Expected length, "window.innerWidt…".
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "browser window" so let's get screen sizes cleared up first because there are actually three of them:

1. Screen Size   (mine is 1920 x 1080 pixels)
2. Browser Size  (mine is 1920 x 1040 pixels)
3. Viewport Size (mine is 1920 x 980 pixels)

To get each of these sets of values use...

1. **screen.width** and **screen.height**
2. **visualViewport.width** and **visualViewport.height**
3. **W.offsetWidth** and **W.offsetHeight**

NB: Where "W" is the window ID.

I know you've accepted the answer by SickerDude43, but I personally wouldn't use that method because the browser may not be full screen at that moment or some other CSS body styling affecting what "100%" really means.

Using one of the above sets of screen values I've given you, is a more robust solution IMHO.

Comment: I have to disagree with you at some points.

VW and VH is the viewport height and width. It also works when the Browser is not at full screen. I use 100vh for a single page application and it works even when not in full screen.

Also a site that is built clean has no problems using the 100%. Actually many people recommend it, especially when you are using flex. This should also be no problem.
The solutions you offer also work. But they are not always better. It really depends. The conclusion however is false. I have no problem with it being the accepted answer, but please correct it

Answer (score 2):

Try it with CSS:

```
<svg ... style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw" ...></svg>
```

Or if you have a container around it you could also use 100%